# What Hibernate dependencies should be supplied with a Glassfish Update Center package?

Tags: hibernate, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm trying to update the Glassfish Hibernate provider from its current 3.5.0 version to 3.6.6.Final.

I need the community's help (and that of the Glassfish developers).  I submitted this question via the email gateway to the Glassfish forums, but the forum system is down again.  In the event it ever comes back, you can find the (equivalent) question here: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/updating-support-hibernate-glassfish-need-communitys-help.  I've also submitted it to the Hibernate forums: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1010771.

The background: if you search on integrating Hibernate with Glassfish, you will get dozens and dozens of articles that all recommend doing one of these things:

- Put Hibernate and its dependencies straight in `domain1/lib`.
- Package Hibernate with your application.
- Install Hibernate from the [Glassfish Update Center](http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/using_the_glassfish_update_center).

Each option as currently manifested has problems, ranging from bugs to classloader problems, or, in the case of the Update Center, version staleness (Hibernate 3.5.0.Final, the version of Hibernate installed by the Update Center, violates the JPA 2.0 JPQL syntax and hence is not JPA 2.0 compatible).  The state can be best summed up with this well-intentioned article: http://eskatos.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/hello-world/  The article itself no longer works, and the update to the article doesn't work either.

Sahoo suggested another approach that I like very much: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/using-hibernate-glassfish#comment-814634

This would place the Hibernate dependencies in their own folder under `domain1/applibs`, referenced by an empty `hibernate.jar` with a `Class-Path:` in its `MANIFEST.MF`.  This is great.  It's isolated, simple to upgrade, compatible with the IPS packaging mechanism, and applications have to specify on deployment with the `--libraries` option that they want Hibernate to be visible.

So, then.  **What goes in that dependencies directory?**  I am not worried about the transitive dependencies, just the Hibernate-authored ones.

In the current Hibernate Update Center package, the dependencies are minimal.  You can see what they are by downloading http://maven.glassfish.org/index.html#view-repositories;Java.net.2~browsestorage~/org/glassfish-repo/packager/hibernate-ips/3.5.0-Final-1/hibernate-ips-3.5.0-Final-1.zip whenever http://maven.glassfish.org is not busy with its usual business function of throwing 503 errors.

The reason they're minimal is that the Hibernate artifact that is installed is `hibernate3.jar`, which seems to be a throw-everything-into-the-punch-bowl distribution of Hibernate, and hence has been stomped mercilessly out of existence in every distribution since.  This fellow has a nice summary: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7686

In Hibernate version 3.6.6, thankfully, this artifact is no longer produced or uploaded to Maven.  Instead, it is expected that you will choose your own dependencies.

That's fine for an individual developer, but when you're talking about providing support at the application server level, what to do?  Include all the optional dependencies?  Some of them?  Which ones?  And that's where I need your help.

From looking at the [`hibernate-all` assembly descriptor](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/3.6/hibernate-distribution/src/assembly/hibernate-all.xml), you can see that the fine folks at Hibernate have replaced `hibernate3.jar` with this recipe.  You can further see that the artifact produced by this descriptor is going to have every single `hibernate-*` module in it.

If I were shooting for a simple upgrade of the existing Hibernate Update Center package, I would probably do what I could to include this, since it's roughly equivalent to the old `hibernate3.jar`.  But I thought I'd ask here first, since the `hibernate3.jar` is kind of an abomination: **What dependencies--and there are many optional ones, cache providers and the like--should Hibernate Update Center support "ship" with?**

As a kind of comparison, you can see that JBoss AS7 ships with a tiny, tiny amount: https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/blob/master/pom.xml#L2696  They do not seem to include the EHCache, SwarmCache or OSCache providers, for example.

So, again, besides `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` (which obviously have to exist in order to have Hibernate work at all), what other dependencies should the Hibernate Update Center package include?